# Cannot access wso2 upgrade document

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

WSO2 api manager 410 from 260 upgrade document is missing. I can google it and see a document. but can't load it. I can remember that there was a document with all the steps. Is it down?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upgrade/migration docs are no longer available publicly. You will need to contact WSO2 Support via Contact Us [1] form in order to get access to these.

[1] - https://wso2.com/contact/

Comment: Is this same for the open source version?

Comment: Yes. If you have a subscription, you can contact the support and get the required assistance. If not, you have to contact wso2.